# Getting error when trying to connect to setup a STOMPClient connection, what could be the issue here?

Tags: java, stomp

Below is the code I have and it throws an error:

```
java.io.EOFException: at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
```

The same credentials & host/port are used with `Python` or `Java` and it works.

This code is failing:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String host = "***********.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
    Integer port = 61614; String userId="******", password="*****";

    StompConnection connection = new StompConnection();
    connection.open(host, port);
    connection.connect(userId, password);
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.readHeaderLine(StompWireFormat.java:155)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.readLine(StompWireFormat.java:148)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.parseAction(StompWireFormat.java:181)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompWireFormat.unmarshal(StompWireFormat.java:98)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection.receive(StompConnection.java:77)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection.receive(StompConnection.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection.connect(StompConnection.java:139)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection.connect(StompConnection.java:132)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection.connect(StompConnection.java:122)
    at com.springboot.nfl.streams.StompListn2.main(StompListn2.java:15)
```

Comment: The code you pasted is for when it does work or does *not* work?

Comment: Also, can you paste the full stack-trace for the `java.io.EOFException`?

Comment: The code which i have put here is not working, i have added the complete error.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompConnection`? My understanding is that it's the STOMP client implementation used internally for the ActiveMQ test-suite and not really meant as a general purpose client.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your stomp client is **not** performing the required **[WebSocket handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3)** upon starting of the connection.

This initial handshake is used to upgrade the HTTP connection to a WebSocket connection, and using Java you will be talking over secure WebSockets while you are directly trying to connect to host. Note that the STOMP client implementation you're using expects a `CONNECTED` frame upon sending `CONNECT`, but since it does not perform the WebSocket handshake it is not receiving it, hence the `EOFException`.
From the [official code example](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-mq-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/amazon-mq-working-java-example.md#-stompwss--1):

```java
private StompSession connect() throws Exception {
    // Create a client.
    final WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
    final WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());

    final WebSocketHttpHeaders headers = new WebSocketHttpHeaders();

    // Create headers with authentication parameters.
    final StompHeaders head = new StompHeaders();
    head.add(StompHeaders.LOGIN, ACTIVE_MQ_USERNAME);
    head.add(StompHeaders.PASSCODE, ACTIVE_MQ_PASSWORD);

    final StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MySessionHandler();

    // Create a connection.
    return stompClient.connect(<wss_endpoint>, headers, head, sessionHandler).get();
}
```

As you can see here the `connect` contains some **headers** and a **session handler** and also they are connecting with a WSS uri. You can replace the headers with your credentials and also the wss endpoint can be got from the AWSMQTT server, see the link I shared above for how the wss uri looks like.

Comment: How do you know `***********.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:61614` is using web sockets and not just standard STOMP? Is that just the way STOMP on Amazon AWS works?

Comment: Using a mere Stomp connection seems to only work in-case of connecting to ActiveMQ running on localhost. Whenever trying to connect to a broker over an external URI this error comes up, and i believe since this broker is on AWS and external source a handshake is hence necessary, for which there might be another medium but it seems by default it goes over websockets as the official code docs support this.

Comment: Thanks Justin Bertram & srinivas kumar..i tried with the example from official site, but it gives error : 22:02:26.024 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession - Failed to connect session id=d829f2a7-5cdb-94c7-6f70-89152c6e706f
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)

Comment: like i mentioned, i have used JS to connect to the stompclient, where it doesn't use the ws stuff. I believe we should be able to do the same with Java as well, i mean without a WSconnection, directly we should be able to connect to stomp client.

Comment: The JS looks like this: const http = require('http');
 const app = require('./app');
 const stomp = require('stomp-client');
 const EventEmitter = require('events');
 
 class MsgNotifier extends EventEmitter {}
 var msgNotifier = new MsgNotifier();

 var stompClient = new stomp(opts);
 stompClient.connect(  
       function(sessionId){
       stompClient.subscribe('/topic/********', function(body, headers)
       {         
           msgNotifier.emit("dag-data",body);
       })
 }); ------------------------- opts will contain the connect URI / UID / PWD.

Comment: You said you got it work with Python, could you please update that too here, it should help with the debugging., also in your working stomp example is the uri a `https` or `wss` connection? Also could you please verify that the websocket uri you used in the java code is valid? This can be easily done using Stomp module in JS. https://medium.com/@debanjanamaitra/stomp-js-in-5-minutes-30ebfb9d6e9a